# How to create PHP insert query based on selected timing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, recursive-query

I want to create an insert query based on the selected start time, end timing and duration of the session. This is for an appointment table.

```
$start_time = 9.am
$end_time = 11.am
$per_session = 30 mins
```

Based on the above options I need to create an insert query.

Expected result

```
 S.no   time    
 1.      9 am
 2.      9.30 am 
 3.      10.00 am
 4.      10.30 am
 5.      11.00 am
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a recursive query - available in MySQL 8.0 only:

```
insert into mytable (sno, time)
with recursive cte as (
    select 1 sno, '09:00:00' time
    union all
    select sno + 1, time + interval 30 minute 
    from cte 
    where time + interval 30 minute <= '11:00:00'
)
select sno, time from cte
```

You can easily turn this to a parameterized query to pass the three parameters as needed.